# C++ compilation error, constructor has no return type... but I didn't specify one

Tags: c++, constructor

So here is the error:
1>c:\users\ben\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl_learning\opengl_learning_without_glut\openglcontext.cpp(18): error C2533: 'OpenGLContext::{ctor}' : constructors not allowed a return type

And here is a block of code where the error points, specifically the error originates from the default constructor:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "OpenGLContext.h"


/**
    Default constructor for the OpenGLContext class. At this stage it does nothing 
    but you can put anything you want here. 
*/
OpenGLContext::OpenGLContext(void){}
OpenGLContext::OpenGLContext(HWND hwnd) { 
    createContext(hwnd); 
}
/** 
    Destructor for our OpenGLContext class which will clean up our rendering context 
    and release the device context from the current window. 
*/  

OpenGLContext::~OpenGLContext(void) { 
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, 0); // Remove the rendering context from our device context
    wglDeleteContext(hrc); // Delete our rendering context 
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc); // Release the device context from our window
}
```

Why!?

Comment: What are the final lines of OpenGLContext.h? My guess is that you have forgotten to close some construct in that file and the compiler therefore assumes that this is the return type of your constructor.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Most likely you forgot a semicolon after `OpenGLContext`'s definition. Then your code is parsed as

```
class OpenGLContext { /* ... */ } OpenGLContext::OpenGLContext(void) { }
```

That's valid syntactically. But as constructors don't have a return type, like the message says, the compiler complains.

Comment: But now there's a weird problem where the project compiles an executable and then cannot find it... I'm beginning to hate C++ more and more.

Comment: Haha 12 years later this helped me on a completely unrelated project 

Answer (score 7):

Missing semicolon after the class definition in the header file

Answer (score 2):

Open the file `OpenGLContext.h` and make sure if you've put semicolon after `OpenGLContext` class definition.

Answer (score 1):

The class definition should have a semicolon at the end.